# How to handle a change in a prop's state after an event is emitted?

Tags: vue.js

I have a parent component (MyCart) which displays the items in the user's shopping cart, and some checkout options. One of these options is to enter a Promo Code, which is the child component.

The way I have it setup is that the PromoCode component has a text field in which the user enters the code. This will emit an event when submitted. The MyCart component listens for this event, and does it's thing (checking to see if the promo code is valid, etc.) and then upon success, sends the promo code's details as a prop to the child component.

The issue is that the prop initially is null (because no promo code has been entered as yet), and for that reason, the different boolean checks I have in place to show error divs, or hide the promo code field when the code is entered, are not accurately updating once the prop is passed after the event is handled.

Here are relevant snippets from my code for both of these components.

MyCart.vue

```
<promo-code :promoCode="promoCode"
            @promo-code-applied="applyPromoCode($event)">
</promo-code>

And in the Script, applyPromoCode(code) basically sets checks to see if the promo 
code is valid, how much discount to apply to the total, and then sets 
this.promoCode = code so that the code is passed as a prop to the child component.
```

PromoCode.vue

```
In the Template

<input v-model="promoCodeInput">
<button @click="applyPromoCode()">

In the Script

props: {
  promoCode: {
    type: Object,
    default: null
  }
},
data () {
  return {
    promoCodeInput: null,
    showPromoCodeField: true,
    showError: false
  }
},
methods: {
  applyPromoCode() {
    this.$emit('promo-code-applied', this.promoCodeInput)
    if (this.promoCode) // this is not being satisfied, even though it should
      this.showPromoCodeField = false
    else // this is the block that is always hit
      this.showError = true
  }
}
```

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out guys! I used a Watcher. So what I did was separate out the code that does the checks (the if/else stuff) into a different function called checkPromoCode, and then I watched for the prop to change, and upon it changing, I called the checkPromoCode function.

Code:

```
In method:
checkPromoCode() {
if (this.promoCode)
  this.showPromoCodeField = false
else
  this.showError = true
}

watch: {
  promoCode: "checkPromoCode"
}
```